# How to access trained parameters in CNTK 2.2 C# API

Tags: c#, cntk

I'm getting to know the new CNTK 2.2 C# API which allows training models from C# as well. I managed to get sample program working, but was wondering how I can access the trained parameter values after training. Found good examples for Python, but none for C#. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction please? Thanks!

Comment: Which demo are you running? I am testing the logistic regression and I have a similar problem. I dont know where are the numerical outputs. In my case, weight and bias. Lets see if we can help each other

Comment: See answer to this:
[CNTK c# logistic regression w and b variable values ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682816/cntk-c-sharp-logistic-regression-w-and-b-variable-values)

Comment: See answer to this: [CNTK c# logistic regression w and b variable values ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682816/cntk-c-sharp-logistic-regression-w-and-b-variable-values)