# CNTK C# API: How does TrainingParameterScheduleDouble work?

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, deep-learning, cntk

I'm trying to understand how `TrainingParameterScheduleDouble` works in the CNTK C# API. Unfortunately, there is no documentation and the previous SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903350/cntk-c-sharp-api-how-to-set-learner-module-and-number-of-iteration-in-learner) appears to be incorrect/incomplete, so I've tried to reverse engineer the behavior myself. Can anyone confirm my conclusions and answer the lingering questions that I have?

**Overload #1**

```
TrainingParameterScheduleDouble(value, minibatchSize)
```

This sets the learning rate to `value` per `minibatchSize` number of samples, regardless of the actual minibatch size passed to `GetNextMinibatch`. Thus, using `minibatchSize: 1` is an easy way to specify a per-sample learning rate.

It seems to me that calling the second parameter `minibatchSize` is very misleading in this context, since it's totally unrelated to the actual size of each minibatch. I think a better name would have been something like `perNumSamples`, or am I missing something?

**Overload #2**

```
TrainingParameterScheduleDouble(value)
```

This is the same as setting `minibatchSize: 0` above, and has the effect of using the "natural" `minibatchSize` that's passed to `GetNextMinibatch` as the number of samples.

So if we have `GetNextMinibatch(64)` then `new TrainingParameterScheduleDouble(0.001)` will result in a 64x *slower* learning rate than `new TrainingParameterScheduleDouble(0.001, 1)`.

**Overload #3**

```
TrainingParameterScheduleDouble(schedule)
```

This changes the learning rate over time, using the "natural" minibatch size. So a schedule of `(30, 0.321), (1, 0.123)` will use a per-actual-minibatch learning rate of 0.321 for the first 30 minibatches and a rate of 0.123 thereafter.

**Overload #4**

```
TrainingParameterScheduleDouble(schedule, epochSize)
```

`epochSize` causes `IsSweepBased()` to return `False` instead of `True`, but otherwise has no apparent effect on the learning rate or anything else. This is surprising. Can anyone explain the purpose of `epochSize` in this context?

**Overload #5**

```
TrainingParameterScheduleDouble(schedule, epochSize, minibatchSize)
```

This is the only way to change the learning rate over time without using the natural minibatch size. So a schedule of `(30, 0.321), (1, 0.123)` with `minibatchSize: 1` will use a per-sample learning rate of 0.321 for the first 30 samples (regardless of the actual minibatch size) and a rate of 0.123 thereafter. As before, the epoch size has no apparent effect.

Assuming this is correct, it's not clear to me what happens if the learning rate changes in the middle of a minibatch. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Great work. The lack of documentation on the CNTK library is incredible.